# Como criar tabela com o plugin de email do android

Tags: android, html, apache-cordova, front-end, webdesign

Olá! Eu estou quebrando minha cabeça desde de manhã e não consigo fazer funcionar.

Usando apenas [esses comandos HTML](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer#html-and-css-on-android) eu preciso criar uma tabela. Seguem os comando se não quiser entrar no site:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela precisa ser algo assim:

```
Nome                       João
Sexo                  Masculino
Idade                   30 anos
Data                 66/66/6666
Saldo                    500,00 <-- essa linha em negrito
```

Eu preciso de algo assim, mas não consigo fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar!??!?

Comment: Sem as tags corretas (por si só, nenhuma destas tags fazem isso) ou sequer suporte a *CSS* (foi isso que entendi do *plugin*), não creio que seja possível obter o resultado que você espera.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues É o que eu acho, mas o cliente precisa disso assim e usando esse troço x.x